# Find critical numbers of $g(t)= t(4-t)^{1/2}$ where $t<3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The question is to find any critical numbers of the function, which is $$g(t)= t(4-t)^{1/2} , \qquad t<3$$

I know that in order to find the critical numbers, I first have to find the derivative and then set that equal to zero. I'm not sure I'm using the chain rule correctly though. Can someone show me how to get to the answer step by step? Your help is much appreciated! This is a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(t)=t(4-t)^{1/2}$. By the product rule, $g'(t)=(4-t)^{1/2}+t(1/2)(4-t)^{-1/2}(-1)$.
We set $g'(t)=0,$ which implies $(4-t)=t/2$. We get $t=8/3$.

Comment: I messed up when I had it equal to zero.

Comment: I know what I did wrong now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad you have figured it out!